# how to get information from a field that is in a loop using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a bunch of image names that is being retrieved from my data base and is in a while loop. In this loop I have a small form with the image names. This form is being use for another purpose. what I want is to get the field information with the item name to a javascript.

Example :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $itemname = $row['name'];
    echo "< input type='hidden' name='$itemname' value='$itemname'>
    <img src='source' onclick='getname()'  width='100%' height='100%' />"; 
}
```

I believe the reason why every image I click on is only giving me the first information from the database is because my id is being duplicated. My question is how can I get the field information to javascript without using the getElementById?

Comment: Actually your fields contain no id's in above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following altered PHP:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $itemname = $row['name']; 
     echo "<input type='hidden' name='".$itemname."[]' id='input$i' value='$itemname' />";
     echo "<img src='source' onclick=\"getname('input$i')\" width='100%' height='100%' />"; 
     $i++;
}
```

Then you can retrieve the input value in Javascript:

```
 function getname(id) {
   var theinput = $('#'+id).val(); // jQuery example
   // do something
```

(I also changed the input name to be an array, of couse you could name it what you want, maybe `$itemname$i` could be an idea, it depends how and if you want to process your form, however the name should be unique or array for good practice)

Here is a working example of HTML/JS: http://jsfiddle.net/fuHSv/1/

Comment: This is not working. When I add the name as an array I receive an error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\member\products.php on line 119). Without the name as an array it does nothing.

Comment: @Bryan Correct you are, you can't make an input array like that. I changed it in my example above. Also added an example of the resulting HTML with a working JS example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fuHSv/1/

Comment: I have made this adjustment and it's still not working. While I was looking at your example I noticed that all the id's are different. The items in the examples are not in a loop. my issue is getting the information that is in a loop.

Comment: @Bryan Well in jsfiddle it's not possible to simulate a server side script. I instead just made a similar resulting code, however the number of items can be of any length and still work. Your PHP loop is still the same. Do you get any errors, WHAT is not working? And can I see your updated code now?

Comment: thanks your example worked the only thing was that for the 'onclick=\"getname('input$i')\"' i change to 'onclick=\"getname('.input$i.')\"' and this works...thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

How about using some jQuery 1.8.2 like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputs = $('input').on('click', function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var val = $(this).val();
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

See [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com) for more.